# can not send response message from httpserver created using java

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpserver

I am creating httpserver in my application, using:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
```

This server first send response message using

```
OutputStream os = httpEx.getResponseBody();
os.write(("your request is being handled, please wait").getBytes());
```

and then opens one jFilechooser. also if anything goes wrong it will throw error using

```
os.write(("Failed to handle your request").getBytes());
```

When my application runs on user's machine, it creates httpserver properly, as I could find through logs but when user sends any request to this server, nothing happens. It displays blank page. But when I remove all `os.write` lines it works fine and displays the filechooser pop-up. I am not aware what is going wrong. Please help me on this.
I have tried these approaches:

```
try {           
            os.write(("Your request is being handled, please wait").getBytes());
            os.close();
            //code to open Jfilechooser pop-up

        } catch (Exception e) {
            os.write(("Failed to handle the request because"+e.getMessage()).getBytes());
            os.close();}
```

and

```
    try {           
                os.write(("Your request is being handled, please wait").getBytes());

                //code to open Jfilechooser pop-up

            } catch (Exception e) {
                os.write(("Failed to handle the request because"+e.getMessage()).getBytes());
                }

os.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I have added os.flush();
as:

```
finally(){
os.flush();
os.close();
is.close();
httpEx.close();

}
```